# Remove Columns and duplicate data

Tags: python, pandas

I Have this dataset.

```
    Route   STOP_ID AveOn   AveOff  AveLd   PassingTime Period  DAYCODE PATTERN_ID  BLK RTE DIR PATTERN_QUALITY VEHICLE_ID  STOP_TYPE   DWELL_SEC   DOOR_OPEN_SEC
0   65  9605    2.1 0   24.2    0.3625  AM  0   11065088    6513    65  N   100 3607    ST  0   0
1   65  9605    2.1 0   24.2    0.3625  AM  0   11065088    6513    65  N   100 3608    ST  0   0
2   65  9605    2.1 0   24.2    0.3625  AM  0   11065088    6513    65  N   100 3664    ST  0   0
3   65  9605    2.1 0   24.2    0.3625  AM  0   11065088    6513    65  N   100 3608    ST  0   0
4   65  9605    2.1 0   24.2    0.3625  AM  0   11065088    6513    65  N   100 3669    ST  0   0
5   65  9605    2.1 0   24.2    0.3625  AM  0   11065088    6513    65  N   100 3620    ST  0   0
2185    67  35322   8.2 0.2 8   0.318055556 AM  0   20067078    6515    67  S   95  3613    ST  1   1
2187    67  35322   8.2 0.2 8   0.318055556 AM  0   20067078    6515    67  S   95  3674    ST  1   1
3976    67  82237   0.2 0.1 6.6 0.692361111 PM  0   20067078    6508    67  S   95  3676    S   1   0
5203    67  35322   4.7 0   4.7 0.33125 AM  0   20067078    6511    67  S   100 3640    ST  1   1
6723    67  35322   7.5 0   7.5 0.369444444 AM  0   20067078    6507    67  S   100 3658    ST  1   1
6730    67  35322   7.5 0   7.5 0.369444444 AM  0   20067078    6507    67  S   100 3673    ST  1   1
```

i do need to delete columns and duplicate rows, and delete values where column (DWELL_SEC) value = 0
i started my code as following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import ExcelWriter
transit="C:\\Users\\Taqwa\\Desktop\\ttest.xlsx"
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(transit)
df=pd.read_excel(transit,'Sheet1')
df.columns=df.columns.astype(str)

writer=ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\Taqwa\\Desktop\\ttest2.xlsx")
df1 = df[df.DWELL_SEC != 0]
for name, sub_df in df.groupby("STOP_ID"):
       sub_df.to_excel( writer, str(name))
writer.save()
```

could anyone help in

Comment: Did you preview the formatting before posting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates` + any boolean indexing function (I've used `query`):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates().query('DWELL_SEC != 0')

df

      Route  STOP_ID  AveOn  AveOff  AveLd  PassingTime Period  DAYCODE  \
2185     67    35322    8.2     0.2    8.0     0.318056     AM        0   
2187     67    35322    8.2     0.2    8.0     0.318056     AM        0   
3976     67    82237    0.2     0.1    6.6     0.692361     PM        0   
5203     67    35322    4.7     0.0    4.7     0.331250     AM        0   
6723     67    35322    7.5     0.0    7.5     0.369444     AM        0   
6730     67    35322    7.5     0.0    7.5     0.369444     AM        0   

      PATTERN_ID   BLK  RTE DIR  PATTERN_QUALITY  VEHICLE_ID STOP_TYPE  \
2185    20067078  6515   67   S               95        3613        ST   
2187    20067078  6515   67   S               95        3674        ST   
3976    20067078  6508   67   S               95        3676         S   
5203    20067078  6511   67   S              100        3640        ST   
6723    20067078  6507   67   S              100        3658        ST   
6730    20067078  6507   67   S              100        3673        ST   

      DWELL_SEC  DOOR_OPEN_SEC  
2185          1              1  
2187          1              1  
3976          1              0  
5203          1              1  
6723          1              1  
6730          1              1
```

---

If `DWELL_SEC` is a string column, convert it first:

```
df.DWELL_SEC = df.DWELL_SEC.astype(int)
df =  df.drop_duplicates().query('DWELL_SEC != 0')
```

Comment: Still, I have the result with DWELL_SEC = 0

Comment: @TaqwaHadidi Check the dtype of that column. Maybe it's a string. Also, make sure you assign the result back: `df = df.drop_duplicates().query('DWELL_SEC != 0')`

Comment: could you help in tow things, I am trying to delete columns but without success, I put the following line   df1 = df[['AveOn','AveOff','AveLd,'DWELL_SEC'']], as well delete the duplicate in 3 columns

Comment: @TaqwaHadidi So you want `df = df[['AveOn','AveOff','AveLd,'DWELL_SEC'']].drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: last question, what if i have column without name??

Comment: @TaqwaHadidi You can refer to column by index: `df.columns[i]` where `i` is the index of that column.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import ExcelWriter
transit="C:\\Users\\Taqwa\\Desktop\\ttest.xlsx"
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(transit)
df=pd.read_excel(transit,'Sheet1')
df.DWELL_SEC = df.DWELL_SEC.astype(int)
df =  df.drop_duplicates().query('DWELL_SEC != 0')
df.columns=df.columns.astype(str)
df1=df[['AveOn','AveOff','AveLd','DWELL_SEC','STOP_ID']]
df2=df1[['AveOn','AveOff','AveLd','DWELL_SEC','STOP_ID']].drop_duplicates()
writer=ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\Taqwa\\Desktop\\ttest2.xlsx")
for name, sub_df2 in df2.groupby("STOP_ID"):
         sub_df2.to_excel( writer, str(name))
writer.save()
```

Comment: Please work on your formatting. Just paste code, highlight it and hit ctrl+K.

Comment: i had not understand it like this